# why do I have to set permissions to 777 in order to be writable

Tags: permissions, security

On my latest ubuntu version install in the public_html folder I have to set folder permissions to 777 in order for the script to save to certain locations within the public html docs. Why is this?

I was under the impression that 755 was/should be ok for reading and on shared hosting accounts that is usually the case, but on my vps system I need to make the folders 777 in order to make the script work.

the script is phpmydirectory but this issue is true of all scripts I may install on the vps.

Is there a way to make folders 755 and writable as I believe 777 to be a security issue?

Any tips appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `chmod 777` is NEVER the solution! It's like drinking vodka, first you feel like your problems are solved, but the next morning you'll wake up with a massive headache (likely caused by a hacked server).

Comment: "Why is this?"  please provide more information on the setup: directory lisitings, usernames are needed to tell you why.

Comment: @Rinzwind The 3 digits refer to 3 different entities: the file-owner, the files-group, and everyone else: 755 says owner has read&write&execute/search and group and other have read&execute/search. 777 says everyone has everything. 7= 4(read)+2(write)+1(search/execute); 5=4(read)+1(search/execute);

Comment: You need to look at the owner, and group of the file.

Comment: @richard why are you telling me that?!

Comment: @Rinzwind because as I looked through the cracks between the books, I only saw the first 3 words of your comment. “Why is this?”, therefore it looked like you were asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to guess: user executing your script doesn't seem to have the required permissions.

For instance, if a php script run by apache web server is used to upload files to a certain subdir, then that subdir should be available for read/write access to your apache user (commonly "apache" or "www-data").

[edit]: when you run a web server, like apache for instance, only the parent process runs as "root", a child process (which is actually the one you care about to run php scripts) usually runs with "www-data" uid on ubuntu/debian platforms.

```
ps auwx | grep apache | grep -v grep
root      1606  0.0  0.0  63520  3020 ?        Ss   déc.01   0:16 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 22325  0.0  0.0 352676  4232 ?        Sl   06:25   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 22326  0.0  0.0 352676  4228 ?        Sl   06:25   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

and that explains why it cannot write to your specific subdir in your public_html, if that specific subdir does not belong to that "www-data" user or group.

To fix this, for instance you can set the "group" attribute of your subdir to "www-data", and set write permission to that group:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data ./public_html/my_files
sudo chmod -R g+w  ./public_html/my_files
```

warning: By doing this, you recursively change the group attribute of ./public_html/my_files to www-data, and allow write access to users belonging to the www-data group, thus allowing apache to (over)write files in that folder.

Comment: all files in public_html are root owned and in root group.

Comment: that's the problem indeed, your web server process cannot write to these dirs, as it is running as a unprivileged user like "www-data", which cannot write into a subdir owned by root (this is the normal behavior) (assuming your web server is apache)

Comment: Thanks the_dude. Il look into makeing those changes soon and post back here when its successful. Thanks again..

Comment: Thanks the_dude for the responses.  However when you say "This is the normal behaviour" you are hinting that I shouldn't make the changes using the commands above. There are no users on the server as it is just a vps that serves a website php files and I am the only one who as access. Do you recommend I change the ownership as you described or leav them as they are owned by the root and using 777 on specific directories for when website users upload a profile pic for example? Thanks again for the response. Much appreciated.

Comment: Were it my own VPS, I would prefer to fix things following what are advocated as good practices, in this case even if 777 on a folder would do the trick for the moment, I would try to stick to the rule: just give minimal permissions to the minimum set of users to achieve your goal.
in this case, the "rule" would be to give write access to the web server user ( ~ "www-data" or "apache"?) on this specific "pictures" or "files" folder you use to upload pics... Never know  what was supposed to be a test would become, and on top of that we prepare our mind and memory to not accept poor standards.